# I'd like to adapt a set of spells from AD&D to the 5th edition. Ask for review together or one by one?

Tags: discussion, questions, homebrew

There is a set of spells available only to the Vhaeraun clergy described in AD&D Demihuman Deities book. They look easily adaptable to D&D 5e and I want to do it and ask for a review.

I want them to be balanced with modern D&D spells, but I'd also want to keep them evenly spaced (they were at 2, 4, 6 and 7 level, as there was no 8 spell level for clerics back then). Thus, asking them together could be more efficient in that matter. But won't it be too much?

Comment: I swear we had two similar Meta questions and I just cannot find them... the search continues

Comment: @Medix2 Can be, but I couldn't find any existing guidelines either.

Comment: Oh yeah, they wouldn't be dupes. But I thought we had some excellently worded answers about this somewhere around here XD

Comment: @Medix2 I don't quite care about duplicate or not here, I care about getting answer :D

Answer (score 9):

You basically homebrew the spells anew.

If they follow a general progression (think: Revivify -> Resurrect -> True Resurrect) then one question seems appropriate. If they are totally independent (fireball & magic missile) make separate questions.